# Generate dict of alphabet

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi so I wanted to generate a dict of the python alphabet in the form

`{'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c'....}`

The link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453576/is-there-a-fast-way-to-generate-a-dict-of-the-alphabet-in-python) was pretty helpful, but when I replace the last 0 in there with string.ascii.lowercase, I get this:

`{'a': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'b': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'c': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'...}`

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm making a cesar cypher. I have to initialize a dict with this form so that I can shift it later.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Comment: And how would that dictionary help in shifting?

Comment: I could edit it after to create the specific cipher that was needed. I'm baking this into a method that has an argument of how many letters to shift it by. for example shift(3) would yield 'a': 'd', 'c': 'f', 'b': 'e' ...

Comment: `dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase))` but you also might find [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) useful

Comment: Yes, creating a mapping from the character to its `ord()` would be more useful.

Comment: Thank you all for your wonderful feedback. Unfortunately, I am too low rated to upvote you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
characters = {}
for character in string.ascii.lowercase:
    characters[character] = character
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
dict([(character,character) for character in string.ascii_lowercase])
```

Or another one:

```
dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase,string.ascii_lowercase))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to make a shifted dictionary:

```
def shiftDict(i):
    i = i % 26
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return dict(zip(alpha,alpha[i:] + alpha[:i]))
```

The for your original question `shiftDict(0)` returns what you asked for.
As another example:

```
>>> d = shiftDict(3)
>>> d
{'u': 'x', 'w': 'z', 'e': 'h', 'r': 'u', 'o': 'r', 'c': 'f', 'x': 'a', 'i': 'l', 'k': 'n', 't': 'w', 'h': 'k', 'j': 'm', 'b': 'e', 'l': 'o', 'y': 'b', 'f': 'i', 's': 'v', 'q': 't', 'm': 'p', 'd': 'g', 'v': 'y', 'p': 's', 'g': 'j', 'z': 'c', 'n': 'q', 'a': 'd'}
```

But for Caesar shifts -- you might want to look into using the string `translate` method.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a dictionary and range?

```
>>> dict = {chr(ord('a') + i) : chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26)}
>>> dict
{'a': 'a', 'c': 'c', 'b': 'b', 'e': 'e', 'd': 'd', 'g': 'g', 'f': 'f', 'i': 'i', 'h': 'h', 'k': 'k', 'j': 'j', 'm': 'm', 'l': 'l', 'o': 'o', 'n': 'n', 'q': 'q', 'p': 'p', 's': 's', 'r': 'r', 'u': 'u', 't': 't', 'w': 'w', 'v': 'v', 'y': 'y', 'x': 'x', 'z': 'z'}
```

And you can make a generic function

```
def gen_alpha_range(start, count):
    return {chr(ord(start) + i) : chr(ord(start) + i) for i in range(count)}

result = gen_alpha_range('A', 5)
print(result)

>>> {'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', 'B': 'B', 'E': 'E', 'D': 'D'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=list(map(chr,range(97,123)))
```

It will return the list which contains all the lowercase alphabets.